# MDB2, Pear, Mysql error

Tags: mysql, pear

ORIGINALLY POSTED ON https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682332/mdb2-pear-mysql-error however as its a server issue thought i may have more luck here.

---

Hi Guys,

I have PEAR, MDB2 and Mysql Driver installed however I keep getting:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function: MDB2_Driver_mysql::_isNewLinkSet(). in /home/**/PEAR/MDB2.php on line 1937.

The Server is CentOS

I am stuck, any help would be appriciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem yesterday.

Try explicitly including the file that contains the MDB2_Driver_mysql class before you call that function. That fixed it for me.  I think this is the path/name to do it:

```
require_once "MDB2/Driver/mysql.php";
```

I know that this question is 4 mos old, but since I stumbled across it someone else might too. I hope this answer helps someone.